# Input type date

Tags: javascript, html, css, date, input

I want to do this:

With a button control the input type date to open calendar to choose date, but the input field can't be shown.
And the result of the date picked is to be shown in another div (this part is resolved).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="date"]').change(function() {

    var outputDate = (this.value);
    $("#target").text(outputDate);
  });
});
```

```css
input[type="date"]{opacity:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="test1"  style="width:100px; height:100px; background:red;display:inline-block;">
<input id="test1" type="date" style="width:100px; height:100px;>
</label>
<p id="target"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="date"]').change(function() {
        var outputDate = (this.value);
        $("#target").text(outputDate);
    });
});
```

```css
input[type="date"]{
    opacity:1;
    position: relative;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    background-color: red;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-clear-button {
    background: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
 }

label {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="test1"  style="width:100px; height:100px; background:red;display:inline-block;">
<input id="test1" type="date" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
</label>
<p id="target"></p>
```